# Nrwl / Nx - how to build single js file consumable by browser with dependencies bundled

Tags: typescript, webpack, rollup, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I need to build a single `js` that can be used as **Service Worker**.

I have a nrwl workspace with two `@nrwl/web:lib` packages, one is `common` and the other is `worker`. The `worker` package uses `common` through `import { stuff } from @my/common`.

With `library` project type `rollup` is used, however, the `worker.umd.js` doesn't contain the `common` dependency, so I need both `common.umd.js` and `worker.umd.js` and have to manually concat them before use as Service Worker.

With `application` project type `webpack` is used which bundles the `common` dependency as well, but also generates other js files, such as `vendor.js`, `polyfills.js` etc. For this, I used `@nrwl/angular` because with `@nrwl/web:application` can't be made publishable.

Is there a better approach? Should I use some other nrwl plugin for this? I'd like to avoid `angular`, `react` if possible, but will use it if need be. Or should I just customize `rollup` or `webpack` config somehow? Or create my own plugin?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, so at last, I've come out with this solution.

I used a `@nrwl/web:application` plugin so that I get a webpack build.

To get rid of multiple js files, I customized the configurations like this:

In `workspace.json` ("worker" is my project):

- added `"vendorChunk": false` to get rid of vendor chunk,
- removed `"polyfills": ...` to remove polyfills chunk,
- removed `"styles"` as I didn't need those,
- added `"webpackConfig": ...` to provide custom webpack config.

This is the relevant part of `workspace.json`.

```json
"worker": {
    "root": "packages/worker",
    "sourceRoot": "packages/worker/src",
    "projectType": "application",
    "architect": {
    "build": {
        "builder": "@nrwl/web:build",
        "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
        "options": {
            "vendorChunk": false,
            "outputPath": "dist/packages/worker",
            "index": "packages/worker/src/index.html",
            "main": "packages/worker/src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "packages/worker/tsconfig.app.json",
            "webpackConfig": "packages/worker/webpack.config.js",
            "scripts": []
        },
...
```

Added the custom `webpack.config.js` to the `worker` project root dir:

```js
module.exports = function (baseConfig) {
    baseConfig.optimization.runtimeChunk = false;
    return baseConfig;
};
```

This is to remove the runtime chunk. I had to do it this way because the `@nrwl/web` plugin doesn't have a `runtimeChunk` option.

All the code from the removed chunks will be included in the main chunk.

That's it, now everything compiles to single `main.js` file which I can load as a Service Worker.

Didn't try to fix publishing yet, but I'd probably just manually add a `package.json` and put it into the `"assets"` in the `workspace.json`.

Comment: This PR is about exposing the `runtimeChunk` option. (not merged yet though)
https://github.com/nrwl/nx/pull/4457

Comment: Glad you found a way. What if I do want polyfills and styles?

Comment: confirmed - with the latest `nx` you don't need a custom `webpack.config.js` - you can just put `"runtimeChunk": false` in `workspace.json`

Comment: I'm on NRWL 14 and `runtimeChunk` still didn't work for me, only the custom webpack config did...